GraphQL Search Query Operation Error: INVALID_OPERATION
Platform Context

Sitecore 10.3.1 XP
Headless Services 21.0.583
GraphQL Endpoint: /sitecore/api/graph/edge

Problem Statement
I'm using the GraphQL Edge endpoint's search query operation to retrieve a list of items under a folder in the content tree.
The template looks like this:



Title
Field Type




Title
Single-Line Text


Description
Rich Text


StartDate
Datetime


EndDate
Datetime


RegistrationLink
General Link



The query is similar to this:
query EventSearch($path: String!, $pageSize: Int = 20, $language: String!) {
  search(
    where: {
      AND: [
        {
          # Descendants of the Event folder
          name: "_path"
          value: $path
          operator: CONTAINS
        }
        {
          # Use the current language context
          name: "_language"
          value: $language
          operator: EQ
        }
        {
          # Template contains the Event template ID
          name: "_templates"
          value: $templateId
          operator: CONTAINS
        }
      ]
    }
    first: $pageSize
  ) {
    total
    pageInfo {
      endCursor
      hasNext
    }
    results {
      ... on Event {      
        title {
          value
        }
        description {
          value
        }
        startDate {
          jsonValue
        }
        endDate {
          jsonValue
        }
        registrationLink {
          jsonValue
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

When I execute the GraphQL query against my ContentManagement role, I get my expected results back:
{
  "data": {
    "search": {
      "total": 27,
      "pageInfo": {
        "endCursor": "MjA=",
        "hasNext": true
      },
      "results": [
        {
          "title": {
            "value": "Evening Social"
          },
          "description": {
            "value": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit nullam, senectus ad sed tempor tellus platea viverra, magna fusce proin aptent hac vehicula morbi."
          },
          "startDate": {
            "jsonValue": {
              "value": "2024-06-02T00:00:00Z"
            }
          },
          "endDate": {
            "jsonValue": {
              "value": "2024-06-02T06:00:00Z"
            }
          },
          "registrationLink": {
            "jsonValue": {
              "value": {
                "href": "https://www.google.com/",
                "linktype": "external",
                "url": "https://www.google.com/"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

When I run the exact same query against the ContentDelivery role the registrationLink field is null and I get an array of INVALID_OPERATION errors at the end of the response.
{
  "data": {
    "search": {
      "total": 26,
      "pageInfo": {
        "endCursor": "MjA=",
        "hasNext": true
      },
      "results": [
        {
          "title": {
            "value": "Evening Social"
          },
          "description": {
            "value": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit nullam, senectus ad sed tempor tellus platea viverra, magna fusce proin aptent hac vehicula morbi."
          },
          "startDate": {
            "jsonValue": {
              "value": "2024-06-02T00:00:00Z"
            }
          },
          "endDate": {
            "jsonValue": {
              "value": "2024-06-02T06:00:00Z"
            }
          },
          "registrationLink": {
            "jsonValue": null
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Error trying to resolve jsonValue.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 55,
          "column": 11
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "search",
        "results",
        "0",
        "registrationLink",
        "jsonValue"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "INVALID_OPERATION"
      }
    }
  ]
}

UPDATE 2024-07-16:
Application Insights provides more detail around the error here:
Exception: GraphQL.ExecutionError
Message: Error trying to resolve jsonValue.

Nested Exception

Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Could not find configuration node: databases/database[@id='master']
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetConfigNode(String xpath, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetDatabase(String name, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetDatabase(String name)
   at Sitecore.Sites.SiteContext.get_Database()
   at Sitecore.XA.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions.Repositories.DatabaseRepository.<GetDatabases>d__7.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at Sitecore.XA.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions.Repositories.ContentRepository.GetItem(ID id)
   at Sitecore.XA.Feature.LayoutServices.Integration.Serialization.FieldSerializers.GeneralLinkFieldSerializer.WriteValue(Field field, JsonTextWriter writer)
   at Sitecore.LayoutService.Serialization.FieldSerializers.BaseFieldSerializer.Serialize(Field field, JsonTextWriter writer)
   at Sitecore.LayoutService.GraphQL.Pipelines.GetFieldContent.SerializeField.Process(GetFieldContentArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.EdgeSchema.Services.FieldContentResolvingService.GetFieldContent(Field field)
   at Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.EdgeSchema.GraphTypes.FieldTypes.ItemFieldGraphType.ResolveJsonValue(ResolveFieldContext`1 resolveFieldContext)
   at GraphQL.Resolvers.FuncFieldResolver`2.GraphQL.Resolvers.IFieldResolver.Resolve(ResolveFieldContext context)
   at GraphQL.Execution.ExecutionStrategy.<ExecuteNodeAsync>d__7.MoveNext()


Maybe verry silly - but are you sure everything is published so the data is equal in master and web database? (both the template as all the related content)

Thanks @Gatogordo, that was the first thing I checked.  The template, fields and content have all been republished.

@ChetCheeto Can you check the site configuration node is pointing to web database as per the latest error shared by you..

@chetcheeto There is something which is accessing the master db node while you are executing the query on your CD server. Please check the configurations of your site, somewhere your master db is being accessed in your CD site.
